# Multisim schematic to other CAD

Tags: multisim, cad

Does anyone knows a way to convert my schematic file in MS14 to any other CAD system? I want to open it with Altium.

Comment: doesn't Multisim have an export function?

Comment: why don't you ask a direct question about what you are actually trying to do? ... `how to import MS14 schematic into Altium?`